# Path - Geometry

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, spectral-theory

I am currently completing the end of a Bachelor degree in pure mathematics. I would like to work on an interesting project (by myself) this summer in the field of spectral geometry. Does someone could essentially offer me some books on which I could work? Better yet, is that someone could describe me a personal project (detailed) that I could take to the summer in the latter area of research?

To describe me roughly, I succeed to obtain $21$ for the PUTNAM contest $2014$. I have experience in differential topology and geometry. I read the books " Differential Topology" of Guillemin and Pollack, "Differential geometry of curves and surfaces" of Do Carmo, a bit of "Morse theory" by John Milnor and finally, "Topology : Point-set and geometric" of Paul L. Shick.

To be a bit more precise, I need someone to present me a project that a professor had given one of his students. I do not wish you to build a new project I could work. From projects that offer me, I will analyze each of them and take what's best for me.

A project for example only be able to prove a certain theorem, and describe me what books I could pass to get there.

Thanks!

Comment: Will you have a local advisor at your university, or will you be working alone?  Do you know Riemannian geometry?  Probably choosing a classical paper will be more effective than a book.

Comment: @icurays1 Actually, I am looking for an intership for the summer. It's hard to find a supervisor at this time of the session. To answer your question, well, this time I'll do a research internship alone.

Comment: @icurays1 Do you have a "classical paper" you could propose to me?

Comment: Re-asked at [Personal project - Spectral geometry](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1743657).

Comment: Do not deface your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer :** I am not an expert in this area.

From what I have understood by some self-reading is that given a Riemannian manifold $M$ we have the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta$ acting on $C^{\infty}(M)$. We can look at the spectrum of this operator. The main idea is that how much of geometry of $M$ can be recovered from analysisng the spectrum of $\Delta$.

As a starting point you can look at [these](http://www.impa.br/opencms/pt/biblioteca/cbm/15CBM/15_CBM_85_07.pdf) notes.

The following webpage is a [graduate course](http://www-home.math.uwo.ca/~masoud/spectralgeometry.html) offered by Masoud Khalkhali at the University of Western Ontario. It has some very useful references.

The following [notes](http://amath.kaist.ac.kr/slemrod/Yau.pdf) by Shing-Tung Yau discuss a lot of open problems in Riemannian Geometry, Geometric Analysis and related areas including Spectral Geometry. I don't know whether problems from these notes will be suitable for a Bachelor's project, but atleast these will give you an idea about the questions in which people are interested.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It is this kind of question I'm interested.

Comment: So far your comment are very useful!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple key books.  I took a course on spectral geometry a few years ago, but I can't find my notes, which had a list of classical papers like Kac 1966 "Can one hear the shape of a drum?" (you should read this one regardless - it's well written and considered a landmark).

- "Eigenvalues in Riemannian Geometry" by Chavel
- "Old and New Aspects in Spectral Geometry" Craioveanu